# How to more effectively find duplicates in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this Data Validation to find duplicates in my Google spreadsheet column:

```
=COUNTIF($D$2:$D,"="&D1) < 2
```

It shows duplicates like this, which are very hard to find when you have thousands of rows (you have to look for the tiny red triangle by scrolling through the whole list). Notice "wing" is duplicated somewhere.

[image]

How can I more effectively find the duplicates? Maybe marking the whole cell as red, or showing a list of the duplicates in another column to the right, so when I click on it it takes me to to the duplicate? Or just showing the list of duplicates in the right would be helpful enough, how can I do that?

So basically:

- Show list of duplicates in another column.
- Mark the duplicates in red in the main/source column.

Comment: How about finding the duplicates and deleting them? There is a specific tool in google sheet, see: `Data -> Data cleanup -> Remove duplicates`